# Point inside closed region between intersected circles

Tags: circles

I have circles (in my example: 3 circles) intersected to each other. There is a closed region between those circles. I have a point K in this closed region. What is the property that fits only for point inside this region. I have one property: Distance between K and each circle centre is greater than the circle radius. However, this property also fits for point outside this closed region, such as K' in my figure. Thanks for any help.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/L3XZIhl.jpg?1]

Comment: You can try using your property and the fact that is inside the triangle with vertices in the centers of the circle

Comment: Assuming that the equation of the dotted circle is known, I hope my answer to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1386360/find-the-length-of-triangle-in-three-intersection-circles can provide some help

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Distance between point and center should be greater than max of radii, and should be inside the triangle formed by circle centers.